# How is the Microsoft Owin implementation for Google Authentication able to authentication without an app Id and app secret?

Tags: .net, authentication, oauth-2.0, owin, google-oauth

The OAuth framework mandates client registration with the authorization and resource server. There is no discovery in OAuth like there is in Open Id.

And in fact, if you try implementing an OAuth client without using any libraries, the Google authorization server is one of the more stricter servers in terms of verifying the redirect_uri and your client application's identity.

Yet, when you use the Microsoft Owin Google Authentication Provider, it is able to authenticate a user with Google without requiring a client registration and a client Id and client secret, and a proper redirect_uri that will be verified by Google.

How does that work? How is Microsoft's Owin implementation able to pull this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually 2 different Google providers in OWIN/Katana 3:

1. [`GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationHandler`](https://github.com/jchannon/katanaproject/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google/GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationHandler.cs): as the name suggest, it's based on OAuth2. Historically, it's the most recent one, and is still supported in July 2015.
2. [`GoogleAuthenticationHandler`](https://github.com/jchannon/katanaproject/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google/GoogleAuthenticationHandler.cs): based on OpenID 2.0, this one was marked as `Obsolete` when Google started deprecating its OpenID 2.0 support: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/auth-migration#timetable. This provider no longer works and you'll be redirected by Google to an help page explaining that OpenID 2.0 support has been removed.

The provider is "automatically" selected by Katana depending on the extension you use in your code: https://github.com/jchannon/katanaproject/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google/GoogleAuthenticationExtensions.cs

Only the OpenID 2.0 provider allows you to authenticate via Google without having to register your app first: if you try to use the OAuth2 provider without specifying a `client_id` and a `client_secret`, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. Just what I wanted to know. :-)